# Dumping from remote server to localhost with postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for a way to dump a database from a Linux server running Ubuntu to my local Windows machine. I'd like to run the pg_dump command directly on the remote server.

Doing it from my local machine would be something like:

```
pg_dump -U user -h HOST -p port -v -d database > C:\Users\..\..dmp
```

But how to do it from the remote server to my local machine? e.g.

```
remote server > c:\..\..
```

Thanks.

Comment: You want to run the pg_dump executable on a remote server, but have the ourput file stored on your local machine?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yes that's the goal if possible

Comment: Is there a problem with running it from your local machine?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Not really, I was just wondering if it was possible at all

Comment: No easy solution that I'm aware of. It seems more like an operating system/networking question really. The fact that it's a postgresql tool producing the file is probably irrelevant. Maybe try adding a new question focusing more on that.

Comment: From Linux to Linux I could see something like `pg_dump ... | ssh  user@host.com "cat > some_name.dmp". Not sure how to do this on Windows without installing compatible programs.